# Multiple tables in single sheet using sheetJS

Tags: javascript, html, excel, sheetjs

I am successfully using the [example from sheetJS's website](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#parsing-workbooks), like so:

```
/* create new workbook */
var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

/* convert table 'table1' to worksheet named "Sheet1" */
var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('table1'));
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws1, "Sheet1");

/* convert table 'table2' to worksheet named "Sheet2" */
var ws2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('table2'));
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws2, "Sheet2");

/* workbook now has 2 worksheets */
```

Is it possible to append multiple html tables to a single sheet? They have the same structure. I imagine it could be something, like so:

```
/* convert 'table1', 'table2', 'table3' to single sheet named "Sheet1" */
var ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('table1'));
var ws2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('table2'));
var ws3 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('table3'));
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, {ws1, ws2, ws3}, "Sheet1");
```

Comment: well, did you find out?

Comment: @aldobsom yup. See answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer from this following link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EebyzQ?editors=0010

What it does is it appends the worksheets into one, skips the header of the first one, and then exports it as an excel sheet:

```
function convert(){
   let tbl1 = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]
   let tbl2 = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1]
      
   let worksheet_tmp1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(tbl1);
   let worksheet_tmp2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(tbl2);
      
   let a = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet_tmp1, { header: 1 })
   let b = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet_tmp2, { header: 1 })
      
   a = a.concat(['']).concat(b)
     
   let worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(a, { skipHeader: true })
   
   const new_workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new()
   XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(new_workbook, worksheet, "worksheet")
   XLSX.writeFile(new_workbook, 'tmp_file.xls')
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for...Cheers!

Comment: I found it from the github page:
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1259

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for three tables based on @md Moazzem answer

```
function convert(section){
    
       var elt = document.getElementById('tbl_exporttable_to_xls');
       var elt2 = document.getElementById('tbl_exporttable_to_xls2');
       var elt3 = document.getElementById('tbl_exporttable_to_xls3');
       let worksheet_tmp1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(elt);
       let worksheet_tmp2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(elt2);
       let worksheet_tmp3 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(elt3);
      
       let a = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet_tmp1, { header: 1 })
       let b = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet_tmp2, { header: 1 })
       let c = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet_tmp3, { header: 1 })
       a = a.concat(['']).concat(b)
       a = a.concat(['']).concat(c)
         
       let worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(a, { skipHeader: true })
    
       const new_workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new()
       XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(new_workbook, worksheet, "worksheet")
       XLSX.writeFile(new_workbook, (section+'-Marks.xlsx')) 
}
```